# Project created under Xcode6 is not adapted the resolution under ios7?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I created a project under the Xcode6,and debug on my iPhone5 with iOS7,but it can not fill the whole screen and show with the resolution 960×640.And it's normal when it run on the 5s with iOS8,why?

update the screenshot,the same empty project,the 1st is on iphone5(ios7),2nd is on 5s(ios8)][image: empty project iphone5(ios7)]

[image: empty project iphone5s(ios8)]

Comment: Not enough information.  Voting to close.

Comment: Yes, please add more information, screenshot or something.

Comment: This issue happens even I try the empty project created under the Xcode 6.